# Post Request in ASP.NET Core returning 404 on Heroku but works locally

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, heroku, asp.net-core-mvc

I have successfully deployed my ASP.NET Core application on Heroku. Everything is working fine but I have post request in my HomeController that doesn't work on Heroku and returns 404. It works fine locally.

**Heroku Log**

```
2017-01-02T07:31:33.818619+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/PostFile" host=myapp.herokuapp.com dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=78ms status=404 bytes=3137
```

**Post request from my Index.cshtml.**

**Variation1**

```
<form action="/PostFile">
```

**Variation2**

```
<form 
 asp-action="PostFile"
 asp-controller="Home"
 method="post"></form>
```

**Post method in HomeController**

```
public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment environment, IDbConnectionFactory dbFacotry)
        {
            _dbFactory=dbFacotry;
            _environment = environment;
        }

       [HttpPost("PostFile")]
       public async Task<IActionResult> PostFile(IFormFile file){
                 *Do Something*
               }
```

**The post request works fine locally but returns 404 on Heroku.**

I have also tried [Route("PostFile")] and it works fine locally and not Heroku.

There are other GET requests/controller actions that work fine on Heroku (returns 200)

**Heroku log for GET request**

```
2017-01-02T07:55:26.116624+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=myapp.herokuapp.com dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=10ms status=200 bytes=4579
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you working with Windows locally? Can you show how you configured the route in startup.cs? You keep saying that it works locally and not on Heroku, but given the code (without knowing the configuration in startup.cs), variation 2 cannot work. You are posting to \Home\PostFile but the controller method PostFile is listening to \PostFile (since you didn't add [Route("[controller]")] to the controller). So perhaps things got mixed up while testing.